# Memory Error While Rotating An Image

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapimage, recycle

I'm trying to do a game in which i have to rotate a bitmap multiple times.But sometimes it shows Out Of Memory Error.How to solve this? Can anyone suggest me a way to recycle a bitmap or any other way out. This is the code I have written :

```
       public void rotate() {
         CustomImageView customImageView=this;
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)customImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(90, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            if (bitmap != b2) {
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception::out of memory in customimage");
        throw ex;
        }
        customImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
```

Comment: May be the image you are rotating is too big. First, scale down the image then rotate it.

Comment: @Hamid Shatu : thanks a lot :) scaling did the job

Answer (score 1):

> OutOfMemoryError is Thrown when the Virtual Machine cannot
>   allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory
>   could be made available by the garbage collector.

your are reallocating your bitmap for every rotate method call try it this way

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)customImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
CustomImageView customImageView=this;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
public void rotate() {
        matrix.setRotate(90, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            if (bitmap != b2) {
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception::out of memory in customimage");
        throw ex;
        }
        customImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
```

> you can also add b2.compress() to compess your bitmap (optional)